# Is it possible to fit sites to iPad/iPhone without media queries, viewports, additional scripts?

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, css, ipad

Whenever I build just a normal site, when viewing the same site on an iPad/iPhone the rendering is always different, where the page is too zoomed in, or the page shifts miles to the left on an orientation switch. I have seen some sites that don't appear to have any additional tools in order for the original site to display as it should (no viewport, media queries or anything), which completely puzzles me. I've tried replicating their code but my sites still end up rendering differently, which is probably something to do with my own methods (which I find to be perfectly up-to-standard anyway).

Is there not a simple method or practice of web development in which all sites will fill a handheld device with no issues, and on orientation the site resizes perfectly? What am I missing out on? Typically I wouldn't give a height to any wrapper elements and the only width I would add is to the main container, but I have a feeling it's something to do with these undefined styles. Thanks.

Comment: you can do two things. first give width:480px to your page or second give width in percantage

Comment: You mention you "have seen some sites".  Can you share what sites you refer to?  It will help people look at these sites and describe what they're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that removing the line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

from the HTML5 Boilerplate html I was using fixed what I was trying to achieve in this instance, but obviously this doesn't allow you to control the viewport on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

What @sandeep said, you can work with percentages.

Maybe the sites you have seen worked with a javascript workaround or did had media queries in their CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Typically percentages for widths and media queries are the way to go.  If the sites you are looking at are doing more there are a few possibilities.  One possibility that comes to mind is that they may be detecting different devices using HTTP headers and sending different CSS at the server level.  This can be valuable, for example, for sending smaller resolution images to smaller browsers that can't use the extra pixels anyway.

Good luck.